# GPA Calc returns an error

Tags: python, algorithm

This is my code, I am trying to make a weighted GPA calculator. The formula I am trying to use for calculating GPA is [Total grade points earned/ total credits attempted]:

```
def gpa_calculator(grades, credit_worth):
    grades = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F']
    credit_worth = [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
    credit_attempt = 0

    if grades == 'A':
        credit_attempt += 4.0
    if grades == 'B':
        credit_attempt += 3.0
    if grades == 'C':
        credit_attempt += 2.0
    if grades == 'D':
        credit_attempt += 1.0
    if grades == 'F':
        credit_attempt += 0.0

    GPA = (sum(credit_attempt)) / (sum(credit_worth))
    return GPA
```

I tested with these:

```
print("Testing gpa_calculator() with grades = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], credit_worth = [4, 3, 2, 3]: " + str(
    gpa_calculator(['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], [4, 3, 2, 3])))  
print("Testing gpa_calculator() with grades = ['F', 'F', 'F', 'F'], credit_worth = [2, 4, 3, 5]: " + str(
    gpa_calculator(['F', 'F', 'F', 'F'], [2, 4, 3, 5])))  
print("Testing gpa_calculator() with grades = ['F','A','B','A','A'], credit_worth = [2,5,5,3,1]: " + str(
    gpa_calculator(['F', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A'], [2, 5, 5, 3, 1])))
```

The return values should be:

```
4.0
0.0
3.1875
```

But I get an error message

```
TypeError: 'int' object is iterable
```

Comment: What's the point of comparing list to letter and sum a int? You need to iterate over list and convert letter grade to integers.

Answer (score 0):

Your code attempts to call `sum()` on `credit_attempt`, which is an integer - 0 in this case:

```
>>> sum(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

The code that sets `credit_attempt` is also wrong:

```
if grades == 'A':
    credit_attempt += 4.0
```

here `grades` is a list, and will never be equal to the string `A`, so `credit_attempt` is never changed from its initial value of 0.

Also, the function immediately overrides the values of the arguments `grades` and `credit_worth` with fixed values.

Comment: So how would I approach this? Would I use a for-loop?

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors here. Let's go through a couple of them, with a full working example below on the bottom. Some of the problems in your code were:

- Even though you take in `grades` and `credit_worth` in `gpa_calculator`, you immediately replace them with set values, meaning the function will always return the same value (if it returns any value)
- You want to iterate through each grade and its corresponding credit value, rather than working with the whole list at once. Since `grades` is a list, it is never equal to any of the strings (e.g. `['A', 'B', 'C'] != 'A'`)
- You sum over `credit_attempt`, but `credit_attempt` is a float, and is already the sum of the amount of credit received. It's also somewhat poorly named, since it's the total credit received, and not total credit attempted.

Here's the working example with these errors fixed, and using a slightly cleaner way of getting GPA values from grade letter strings:

```
def gpa_calculator(grades, credit_worth):
    gpa_value_dict = {
        'A': 4.0,
        'B': 3.0,
        'C': 2.0,
        'D': 1.0,
        'F': 0.0,
    }
    total_credit = 0
    for grade, credit in zip(grades, credit_worth):
        total_credit += gpa_value_dict[grade] * credit

    GPA = total_credit / sum(credit_worth)
    return GPA

print("Testing gpa_calculator() with grades = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], credit_worth = [4, 3, 2, 3]: " + str(
    gpa_calculator(['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], [4, 3, 2, 3])))  
print("Testing gpa_calculator() with grades = ['F', 'F', 'F', 'F'], credit_worth = [2, 4, 3, 5]: " + str(
    gpa_calculator(['F', 'F', 'F', 'F'], [2, 4, 3, 5])))  
print("Testing gpa_calculator() with grades = ['F','A','B','A','A'], credit_worth = [2,5,5,3,1]: " + str(
    gpa_calculator(['F', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A'], [2, 5, 5, 3, 1])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because the `credit_attempt` variable is single value, an int, and therefore not iterable. `sum()` is designed to act on an iterable object such as a list. You can initialize with `credit_attempt = []` to create an empty list instead.

I should also point out that the function parameters you pass in aren't going to be used anywhere because you immediately overwrite them with static lists at the top of the function.